# How to reduce the size of ear file

Tags: spring, maven, websphere, ear, filesize

The size of my EAR file has reached around 100 MB after adding many exetrnal jars.

Environment : Java Spring/Websphere application server/Maven

Please share the tips to reduce the size of an EAR file.

Seems the exteral jars contribute most to the large size.  Is it possible to follow an approach like below, if so how to do that?

1. Do the maven build with compile scope for large jars
2. Keep the large sized jars in app server lib, with this will the app take these jars at runtime from appserver?

Thanks
Smitha

Comment: How many applications are in your EAR? Are there big resources inside the EAR like pictures? How many of the 100MB are libs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really review your jars, especially poorly done Maven builds add a lot of unnecessary jars to the application (like jta, servlet, jee-api, etc..), so make sure you don't have them. Sometimes jars are duplicated in every web module you have in the EAR.

Second WebSphere is Java EE 6 server, so it provides lots of common features like JAX-WS, JAX-RS, JPA, etc..., so you should consider using them, before throwing all that as third party libraries in your application.

If you want to use shared library approach, **do not** put the jars in the server `lib` folder or server classpath. This is not recommended.
Create Shared library via `Environment > Shared libraries` see [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib_create.html?lang=en) and assign them to the application.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the War size you can consider

1. Static Content :Keep the Static content like images etc out of the war file and refer them via application using references to location.
2. Shared Libs : if majority of the size is contributed by Shared Libs you can separate that out of war. to do that you can place the war libraries in one of the following locations 
   a) In Server Lib folder, Not Recommended since different apps might use diff versions.
   b) In Server App Lib Folder
   b) In a shared folder and including that folder into class path .
   c) Use exploded war deployment deploying only changes.